# How to run periodic tasks with yeoman angular-fullstack

Tags: npm, gruntjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I would like to periodically (lets say, every 24 hours) run a JS file that reads and writes data with mongoose, using yeoman angular-fullstack. What is the best practice to do so?

Eli

Comment: Might be, yet the grunt runs as a process - wouldn't it be easier to just create a grunt task?

Comment: You need a scheduler to periodically run tasks.  Start with Cron